# How to put content over/on top of particle.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles.js

[image: EDIT: used grid containers which worked but the particles.js interactivity is gone]So I am trying to create a navigation and footer in the body of the website but the particle.js keeps coming over those elements. I have tried z-index and it doesn't bring it up. The particle.js is not allowing me to touch my navigation bar or footer. Would appreciate some help.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Blog</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/blog.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="index.html" >Home</a>
        <a href="aboutMe.html">About Me</a>
        <a href="resume.html">Resume</a>
        <a href="blog.html" class="active">Blog</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
            if (x.className === "topnav") {
                x.className += " responsive";
            } else {
                x.className = "topnav";
            }
        }
    </script>
    <div id="particles-js">
        <p style="color: white; font-size: 30px;">Coming soon!</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/particles.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <div class="footer">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <img alt="LinkedIn" src="images/linkedin.png" id="linkedin">
        </a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <img alt="Github" src="images/github.png" id="github">
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  /*height: 100vh;*/
}

#particles-js{
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;*/
  background: #8000FF;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}

.particles-js-canvas-el{
  position: absolute;
}


.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #8000FF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Brush Script MT";
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #8000FF;
  color: white;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #8000FF;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
    .topnav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.footer{
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index:999;
}

.footer [alt = "LinkedIn"],[alt="Github"]{
  float: right;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

particle.js:

```
var pJS = function(tag_id, params){

  var canvas_el = document.querySelector('#'+tag_id+' > .particles-js-canvas-el');

  /* particles.js variables with default values */
  this.pJS = {
    canvas: {
      el: canvas_el,
      w: canvas_el.offsetWidth,
      h: canvas_el.offsetHeight
    },
    particles: {
      number: {
        value: 400,
        density: {
          enable: true,
          value_area: 800
        }
      },
      color: {
        value: '#fff'
      },
      shape: {
        type: 'circle',
        stroke: {
          width: 0,
          color: '#ff0000'
        },
        polygon: {
          nb_sides: 5
        },
        image: {
          src: '',
          width: 100,
          height: 100
        }
      },
      opacity: {
        value: 1,
        random: false,
        anim: {
          enable: false,
          speed: 2,
          opacity_min: 0,
          sync: false
        }
      },
      size: {
        value: 20,
        random: false,
        anim: {
          enable: false,
          speed: 20,
          size_min: 0,
          sync: false
        }
      },
      line_linked: {
        enable: true,
        distance: 100,
        color: '#fff',
        opacity: 1,
        width: 1
      },
      move: {
        enable: true,
        speed: 2,
        direction: 'none',
        random: false,
        straight: false,
        out_mode: 'out',
        bounce: false,
        attract: {
          enable: false,
          rotateX: 3000,
          rotateY: 3000
        }
      },
      array: []
    },
    interactivity: {
      detect_on: 'canvas',
      events: {
        onhover: {
          enable: true,
          mode: 'grab'
        },
        onclick: {
          enable: true,
          mode: 'push'
        },
        resize: true
      },
      modes: {
        grab:{
          distance: 100,
          line_linked:{
            opacity: 1
          }
        },
        bubble:{
          distance: 200,
          size: 80,
          duration: 0.4
        },
        repulse:{
          distance: 200,
          duration: 0.4
        },
        push:{
          particles_nb: 4
        },
        remove:{
          particles_nb: 2
        }
      },
      mouse:{}
    },
    retina_detect: false,
    fn: {
      interact: {},
      modes: {},
      vendors:{}
    },
    tmp: {}
  };
```

Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `position: fixed`
instead of absolute

and use z-index of interactive div  to something higher than one

and lastly don't keep anything inside the div that shows the particles..

[image]
I know Its not much understandable as you are not using React.js
but the problem you are incurring would be solved with this.

so my `<Particle/>` component contains the particles.js file and all my other `<div>` and other content starts from `<Navigation />` to `<FaceRecognition />`

if you can see i have used a class `particles` for my particles component. Here is its styling

```
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

and all my other `<div>` have `z-index` of more than 1.
Here is the output

[image]

Comment: so I should but a z-index of something higher than one in the navigation bar and footer class?

Comment: Also, if I want content in the middle of the particle.js, I still don't have to keep anything inside the div?

Comment: I am afraid that didn't work. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Raunak, I would let you know the error, if you share the output also. 
Apart from that i am using Reactjs for the same particles file 
and did the same. Check out my repo on how i did it. i also sending the Code screenshot where i have placed the particle js file.
https://github.com/developersbeat/face-recognition

Comment: Hey Sarthak, so right now I tried using grid containers which worked but the particles.js don't have the interactivity as they initially did. I have added the screenshot the question.

Comment: Open your inspect element of your browser and check whether the ```<div>``` with coming soon content is not covering the whole display area. For example my ```div``` with detect button is covering full width. So, the particles would not be interactive at that place. https://prnt.sc/ua7sld

Comment: I tried that. Seems the "coming soon" content barely covers any area. Is there anything else I can do besides using React, because I am not as familiar with it. https://prnt.sc/ua83vv

Comment: https://codepen.io/creotip/pen/jEWGQM
is this helpful  ?

Comment: Absolutely! Thank you so much.