# can't create div below particles-js header

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Edit : [image]
Codepen: https://codepen.io/MOSTAFAEZZAT/pen/JjrPMRm
Every div I create becomes on the header itself specifically this class `<p class="lead">` (there is image at the end), I tried many stuff like change position from `absloute` to `fixed` it was having strange behaviour

Html code after the navbar

```
    <div id="particles-js">
      
    </div>
          
    <div class="container">
    
      <div class="forms" >
        <div class="text" > 
        <h4 class="h1 display-1 text-uppercase"> SEO Video Analyzer </h4>
        <p class="lead  centered">Start use paste your video link to analyze and increase your subscribers</p>
      </div>
       
              
     
      <form class="d-flex   justify-content-center " method="GET" action="index.php">
    
            <div class="input-group  col-lg-4 mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="url"  placeholder="Enter Youtube Video URL"   aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
            <input class="btn" value="Analyze" name="submit" type="submit"   id="button-addon1"></input>
            </div>
      </form>  
      </div>
    </div>
  
 <div class="container" >

 <p class="lead">Start use paste your video link to analyze and increase your subscribers</p>
 </div>

      
       
<script src="bootstrap\particles.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap\app.js"></script>
```

Css code

```
 body {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif !important;
 } 
 
  
  /* ---- particles.js container ---- */
  canvas {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }

  
  #particles-js {
  
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:whitesmoke;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    background-image: url("");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
   
  /* ---- stats.js ---- */
  
  .count-particles{
    
    background: #000022;
    position: fixed;
    top: 48px;
    left: 0;
    width: 80px;
    color: #13E8E9;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 4px;
    line-height: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  
  .js-count-particles{
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
  
  #stats,
  .count-particles{
    -webkit-user-select: none;
  }
  
  #stats{
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .count-particles{
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  }

.navbar {

    background-color:#6a329f ;
    color:white;
     opacity: 0.8;
   
    padding: 10px;   
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.navbar-toggler{

    color:black;
}

 
  
.forms{

    margin-top: 150px;

}  

.page-header{


   /* background-image: url(../bootstrap/blockchain.jpg);*/
    background: cover;
   /* background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(247, 37, 133,1), rgba(181, 23, 158,1) ,  rgba(86, 11, 173, 1)  , rgba(86, 11, 173, 1),
     rgba(72, 12, 168, 1),rgba(58, 12, 163, 1),rgba(63, 55, 201,1) ,rgba(67, 97, 238,1) );
    opacity: 0.5;*/
    
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}


.h1{
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif !important;
    color: #6a329f;
    font-size: 50px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.lead{


    text-align: center;
    color: #6a329f;
    font-size: larger;

}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Johnn, please put your code into a pen so this doesn't get marked closed: https://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: Can you be more precise like where when div is added is causing the issue and what is expected. I see you have 2 container and each has <p> with class "lead"

Comment: Could you isolate the problem? By that I mean removing all code that doesn't contribute too the problem. That way people can more easily see what needs fixing.

Comment: @Jibin.Jay the idea is any div i add after `<div id="particles-js">` I presented on the header which is `<div id="particles-js">` (the header) not after it whether div or `<p>` anything

Comment: @LouisbBoucquet the code in the question is completely precisely and it's from  `<div id="particles-js">` only which is the problem but the code in the code pen is the whole code

Comment: @Jibin.Jay Yes indeed 2 classes with container with class "lead" but i just use containers for making the div in the center all i just concern about is making new div after the header

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly then the absolute position in the "particles-js" is what causing the container to be inside the "particles-js"

Comment: Jibin's solution worked for me, after removing the absolute position from `#particle-js` in the CSS, the subsequent divs appear below it.

Comment: @JohnnDoe If you want the header "SEO Video Analyzer" inside the "particle-js" then move the h4 under the "particle-js" div.

Comment: @Jibin.Jay Yes you alright i changed to relative , it makes the speech that i want to display on the header doesn't look correct it's like there is a background i'll edit the question to show you

Comment: `<div id="particles-js">
<h4 class="h1 display-1 text-uppercase"> SEO Video Analyzer </h4>
  <p>Start use paste your video link to analyze and increase your subscribers</p>
     
  <form class="d-flex   justify-content-center " method="GET" action="index.php">
<div class="input-group  col-lg-4 mb-3">
<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="url"  placeholder="Enter Youtube Video URL"   aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
<input class="btn" value="Analyze" name="submit" type="submit"   id="button-addon1"></input>
</div>
</form> 
</div>`

Comment: @Jibin.Jay I edited the question and i'm using z-index for particles= -1 and the other more than 1 and `background: transpartent;` and also same problem

Comment: In summary particle-js div doesn't flow under SEO Video or the input itself

Comment: @JohnnDoe Is the image at beginning of your question your expected output?
If yes, then move "particles-js" div at the bottom i.e. after the last continer

Comment: @Jibin.Jay this image after we changed the position but it has a background makes the particle doesn't flow and doesn't have transparent

Comment: https://codepen.io/mattrees92/pen/vYmKvNo
Like this example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63694269/how-to-put-content-over-on-top-of-particle-js

and exactly like that